# efficiently calculate annual cumulative sum

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset with quarterly transactions. `PERIOD` represents the quarter of the transaction and `INCREM` represents the incremental amounts.

```
tbl <- data.frame(PERIOD = c(2,3,6,10,11),
                  INCREM = c(10,50,-30,-10,-20))
```

I want to get annual cumulative sums (so the cumulative sum at periods 4, 8, 12).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tbl %>%
  mutate(CUMSUM = cumsum(INCREM)) %>%
  select(-INCREM) %>%
  mutate(PERIOD = factor(PERIOD, 1:12)) %>%
  complete(PERIOD) %>%
  fill(CUMSUM) %>%
  mutate(PERIOD = as.numeric(PERIOD)) %>%
  filter(PERIOD %% 4 == 0)
```

Result:

```
  PERIOD CUMSUM
1      4     60
2      8     30
3     12      0
```

This works, but it's not very efficient. The original dataset is 5 rows and the final dataset is 3 rows, but in the middle of the `dplyr` chain (after `fill()`) the dataset is 12 rows.

Is there a more efficient way to get the annual cumulative sums?

Also, my actual data is coming from a database query. Do you think it would be better for me to take care of this cumulative summing in the SQL query before manipulating in R?

Comment: I'd investigate `cut` as a means to making the groups without needing to `fill()` - `cut(tbl$PERIOD, c(1,4,8,12), labels=c(4,8,12), include.lowest=TRUE)` for instance as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @thelatemail suggested you can use `cut` to create groups, then `sum` values in each group and finally `cumsum` over all the values.

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>%
  group_by(quarter = cut(PERIOD, c(1,4,8,Inf), labels=c(4,8,12))) %>%
  summarise(CUMSUM = sum(INCREM)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(CUMSUM = cumsum(CUMSUM))

#  quarter CUMSUM
#  <fct>    <dbl>
#1   4       60
#2   8       30
#3  12        0
```

---

Using same logic an overly complicated base R approach to fit in one line is

```
transform(aggregate(INCREM~PERIOD, 
  transform(tbl, PERIOD = cut(PERIOD, c(1,4,8,Inf), labels=c(4,8,12))), sum), 
    INCREM = cumsum(INCREM))


#  PERIOD INCREM
#1      4     60
#2      8     30
#3     12      0
```

which actually means

```
tbl$PERIOD <- cut(tbl$PERIOD, c(1,4,8,Inf), labels=c(4,8,12))
tbl1 <- aggregate(INCREM~PERIOD, tbl, sum)
tbl1$INCREM <- cumsum(tbl1$INCREM)
```

Answer (score 3):

cut is definitely the way to go. You can also just calculate the cumulative sum and then keep the final rows of the period. This avoids the aggregate step.

```
tbl$prd <- cut(tbl$PERIOD, c(1,4,8,Inf), labels=c(4,8,12))
tbl$cumsum <- cumsum(tbl$INCREM)
tbl[!duplicated(tbl$prd, fromLast=TRUE),c("prd","cumsum")]
#   prd cumsum
# 2   4     60
# 3   8     30
# 5  12      0
```